# math.stackexchange question mentioned on TechCrunch!

Tags: discussion, publicity

Congratulations to [Qiaochu Yuan](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/232/qiaochu-yuan) for your answer on "[Mathematical difference between white and black notes in a piano?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11669/mathematical-difference-between-white-and-black-notes-in-a-piano)", which already has 69 upvotes and over 5000 views... this morning your answer was [mentioned in TechCrunch](http://techcrunch.com/2010/11/25/stack-overflow-hits-10m-uniques-boldly-goes-where-no-qa-site-has-gone-before/) as an example of the high quality answers that make Stack Exchange successful!

We are totally in awe of awesome people like you who are making the internet a better place. Thanks.

Comment: Congratulations indeed to Qiaochu! Please don't let the rock star status get to your head too much... :D

Comment: And thank you for all your work on the SE platform!

Comment: Also featured on Hacker News, grats! http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=1940474

Comment: I just wanted to say I wish I could give Qiaochu a prize or something!  Every time he answers one of my questions, the answer is always spectacular, and it means so much to me that I make sure to always answer one or two math/physics questions by younger students on this on other forums.  Keep up the good work!

Answer (score 12):

Thanks to the many senior and established mathematicians spending their time answering questions around here. And to the less senior, nevertheless enthusiastic and diligent members of of the mathematical community. All have contributed high-quality answers.

And finally thanks to all the anonymous users for all the effort they spent on the site. An interesting side-remark is that one of them, [Moron](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1102/moron), has a somewhat misleading pseudonym!

Comment: As a side remark, I've already seen some people with last name Moron.